# Listing data from 3 different but associated table into one dropdown (using linq-to-sql and mvc3)

Tags: sql, asp.net-mvc-3, linq-to-sql, drop-down-menu

i ve 3 tables in my database : `item`,`group`,`groupdetail`;

in table `item` there are 2 fields : `id`,`item_name` (bigint"long",string)

in table `group` there are 2 fields : `id`,`group_name` (bigint,string)

in table `group_details` there are 3 fields : `id`,`group_id`,`item_id` (bigint,bigint,bigint)

`group_id` is nullable cause some items have no groups.

what i want to do is listing the names of groups where the items that has a group "`group_name`" ordered by `item_id` and also in the same list i wanna show the item names which has no group and both of them should be ordered by `item_id`

i can also fill dropdowns with jquery if required for this action but i'm brain freezed with listing part.

controller

```
 var data = from guru in dataContext.group_details select guru;

 var itemsWithoutGroup = data.Where(c => c.group_id == null).OrderBy(c => c.item_id).Where(c => c.item_id == c.item.id).Select( c=>c.item.item_name);

 var groups = data.Where(c => c.group_id != null).OrderBy(c => c.item_id).Where(c => c.group_id  == c.group.id).Select( c=>c.group.group_name);

 var grandlist = // i wanna do smt here to list both in one dropdown ordered by item_id
```

view

```
@Html.DropDownList("GroupDetails", new SelectList((System.Collections.IEnumerable)ViewData["GroupDetailedList"], "id", "item_id"))
```

**EDIT:**

To be more specific about it..

```
Group-1 
Group-2
Item-9
Group-3
Item-15
Group-4
```

So this is how the dropdown should look like! Items with no groups should be listed too with the item groups and be ordered by item_id..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The statement i would use is:

```
var groupswithItems = (from groupdetail in group_details select groupdetail.group_id
                     join group in groups groupdetail.group_id equals group.id
                     orderby groupdetail.item_id
                     select new SelectListItem {Text= group.name, Value= group.id.ToString() }).ToList()

var itemswithotgroups = (from item in items orderby item.id select new SelectListItem { Text= item.name, Value= item.id.ToString() }).ToList()

ViewBag.Combined = groupswithItems.union(itemswithotgroups);
```

This would give you the list from all groups that are in group detail (those contain items i presume) and convert it to object that Dropdownlist can handle

```
@Html.DropDownList("GroupDetails", ViewBag.groups as List<SelectListItem>))
```

Comment: yes it gives the groupnames of items that has groups but i also wanna list the items that doesnt have a group with those groups..

Comment: basically you want to list all the items?

Comment: not exactly i wanna list items with no group and groups with items

Comment: im really sorry about my bad usage of english.

Comment: I think latest edit should be it. It is created without any editor so there can some syntax error. This creates a group off items that shouw groups with items and then the items without group

Comment: it make sense so it should do the job ty!

Comment: well i tried but it didnt solve problem. ur logic is true but its not the best way to do it got too many problems with this one. ill try using json call to fill the dropdown with both items and groups.